# Cookies set as "secure" do not appear in Chrome and IE

Tags: java, cookies, web

I've been working in a Java web app and I've set my cookies to be secure, by using cookie.setSecure(true).

The problem is when I run my application and I try to access it using Chrome or IE, the cookies set to secure do not appear, even if they are set in the HTTP response.

However, if I try to access my web app using Firefox, the cookies works fine.

My environment:

- Java 6
- Spring MVC
- Servlet 2.5
- Tomcat 6
- Windows 7

Does somebody have some idea about that?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably your connection in Chrome and IE isn't secure.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly because you aren't using an SSL connection. Some browsers only send cookies marked secure when transmitting over SSL.

Ref: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag